# React Native:"go back" function

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

is there a way to disable the "goBack" function in react-navigation? basically i have a page (example page A) where people do the login, and then this page go to another page (example page B). i want to disable the goBack from page B to page A.

```
export default class ChatDisponibili extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: "CHAT DISPONIBILI",
    headerStyle: {
      backgroundColor: '#3498db',
    },
    headerTintColor: '#fff',
    headerTitleStyle: {
      fontWeight: 'bold',
    }
  };

  ........................

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <ScrollView>
          <FlatList
            data={this.state.data}
            keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
            renderItem={this._renderItem}
          />
        </ScrollView>
        <View style={styles.footer}>
          <Text style={styles.footerTesto}>FOOTER DA CAMBIARE</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: are you using stackNavigator? you can remove the back button by removing the header

Comment: i'm using react-native+react-navigation. if i delete the header i still have the arrow that can make the user go back to the previous page

Comment: can you show me parts of your code? cause if you use `headerMode:'none'` , the arrow shouldnt be there anymore

Comment: yes, i just edited the post. the code is from the page "B". i started learning RN 2 weeks ago, so i'm sorry if i suck at it lol

Comment: oh lol no worries. I guess, it's because you use header in navigationOptions. You can just make your own custom header under View instead

Comment: thanks man, it worked! i just set "header: null" in the navigationOptions and it worked. basically i disabled the header just like you said

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you can add headerLeft

```
 static navigationOptions = {
    title: "CHAT DISPONIBILI",
    headerStyle: {
      backgroundColor: '#3498db',
    },
    headerTintColor: '#fff',
    headerTitleStyle: {
      fontWeight: 'bold',
    },
    headerLeft:()=>null
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Disabling header to 'none' is just a way to disable header from your page. Android user can still click native back button to go back. So you also need to disable native android button.

```
import {  BackHandler } from 'react-native'
componentDidMount() {
        BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', () => {
            return true;
          });

    }
```

This can access you to handle android back button. For more information about handling android back button please visit: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/backhandler.html

Comment: So, you need to use switch navigator: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/switch-navigator.html